# How to make scrollbar invisible - transparent

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

Hey is it possible to make scrollbar "hidden" i dont wanna use overflow-y: hidden
just something like background: transparent or something like that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kurlak/2013/11/03/hiding-vertical-scrollbars-with-pure-css-in-chrome-ie-6-firefox-opera-and-safari/) you will find a description how to hide the scrollbar just with CSS.
And here in the second [example](http://jsfiddle.net/tovic/Uz7wc/) you will find a solution how to hide the scrollbar within a div for example.
The trick in the second example is to define a wider div container that the surrounding one.

```
.hidden-scrollbar .inner {
   height:200px;
   overflow:auto;
   margin:15px -300px 15px 15px;
   padding-right:300px;
}
```

Just play arround with the values of margin and padding.

Answer (score 6):

There is a CSS rule that can hide scrollbars in Webkit-based browsers (Chrome and Safari).  That rule is:

```
.element::-webkit-scrollbar { width: 0 !important }
```

u can change width / background-color and other properties .

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 12px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0); 
    border-radius: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0); 
}
```

this css code might work

Comment: [Not supported by Firefox](https://caniuse.com/#search=-webkit-scrollbar) though.

Comment: Firefox has [scrollbar-width](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scrollbar-width).

Answer (score 4):

In Webkit browsers:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar { 
    display: none; 
}
```