# Set a scrollbar transparent with a background image visible behind it

Tags: html, css, firefox, scrollbar

I use custom scrollbars on my site, and I was wondering if it's possible to have the background image of the `body` **behind** my scrollbar, as it works well with `textarea`.

**Edit:** I want the scrollbar to be still usable with the cursor.

```css
textarea {
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-image: url(https://barrycap.com/assets/bg/home.svg);
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  resize: none;
  scrollbar-color: #888f #fff0;
}
body {
  background-color: #222;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-image: url(https://barrycap.com/assets/bg/random.svg);
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  resize: none;
  scrollbar-color: #888f #0000;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <textarea>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</textarea>
    <textarea>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</textarea>
  </body>
</html>
```

I didn't saw it in the first place, but the scrollbar colors don't work on Chrome (I posted my question on Firefox). I've got another method for [my site](https://barrycap.com) on Chrome.

Here is a screenshot of the snippet in Firefox:
[image: screenshot]

**Edit:** The question has been answered for **Chrome** by **@HereticMonkey**.
But the transparent scrollbar track for the `body` doesn't work in **Firefox**.

I changed the background color and background image of the body to make the issue an evidence.

Comment: Use `overflow: hidden` to hide scrollbars.

Comment: I don't want to hide scrollbars, I just want the background to be visible behind the scrollbar.

Comment: Then I guess this post will help you out [How to make scrollbar invisible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37298627/how-to-make-scrollbar-invisible-transparent/37300691)

Comment: @CRishi he doesnt want to make scroll bar invisible, he wants to put an image behind the scroll bar that is visible

Comment: There are a number of questions about the scrollbar. [Make Scrollbar track transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50837011/215552), [Transparent scrollbar with css](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23200639/215552)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Transparent scrollbar with css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23200639/transparent-scrollbar-with-css)

Comment: @Heretic Monkey Partly, because it works great in Chrome, but not at all in Firefox, as it uses `webkit` and not `scrollbar-color`. But thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Add this CSS:

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
}
    
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background-color:transparent;
}
    
::-webkit-scrollbar-track:hover {
  background-color: #eaeaea;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #888;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me, either on Chrome or Firefox. However, the custom scrollbar works in Chrome.

Comment: are you open to use _open source third party libraries_ in your code?

Comment: You can always suggest…